# Explain the time complexity whether it is O(n) or O(n^2)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have a doubt with time complexity

Getting n from user

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++){
    //some code
}
```

Time complexity is O(n)

```
for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
        //some code
}
```

Time complexity is O(n)(seen from online).How it is O(n).

```
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++)
{
    for(int i=0;i<=n;i++)
        //some code
}
```

what is the time complexity for above code ? Is it is O(n) or O(n^2)?

Comment: What do you *think* it is, why, and why do you "have a doubt"?

Answer (score -1):

If you know a process has a time complexity of O(), like your example of this loop:

```c
for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
    //some code that has a time complexity of O(1)
}
```

...then repeating the process a constant number of times, will not change the time complexity:

```c
for (int j = 0; j <= 10; j++) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        //some code that has a time complexity of O(1)
    }
}
```

In other words, O(10) = O().

You can find some rules of working with time complexity on [Wikiepia - Big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties):

> #### Multiplication by a constant
>
> Let  be a nonzero constant. Then (||⋅)=(). In other words, if =(), then
> ⋅=().

Answer (score -1):

If you don't like handwaving, you should apply elementary calculus and use [the limit definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann%E2%80%93Landau_notations). So if you plug in your f(n) = 10n and g(n) = n, you will see that 10 is less than infinity, and thus f(n) = 10n = O(g(n)) and you are done.